# MySQL get multiple rows in a single table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the stucture of the DB table that was handed to me.
No Id, just name and value.

```
|option_name  | option_value|
 | Item1      | Value |
 | Item2      | Value |
 | Item3      | Value |
 | 2ndItem1   | Value |
 | 2ndItem2   | Value |
 | 2ndItem3   | Value |
 | ThirdItem1 | Value |
 | ThirdItem1 | Value |
 | ThirdItem1 | Value |
```

The statement I would like to have would put the data to something like one of these:

```
| item1.value | 2ndItem1.value | ThirdItem1.value|
| item2.value, 2ndItem2, ThirdItem2|
```

There is only a handful of names that I need to match together (about 7-8) so it's not a big deal to match them together by hand if that's what it takes

Not sure if a JOIN is the right tool for the job, or a loop or.. well I'll let you give me the advice.

I am going to be using this in a Drupal Migration, which is why I'd like to create this as a MYSQL query.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with us?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't exactly know where to start with this one. I did lots of googling.

Comment: What are the column names?

Comment: Is it really just two columns?  It looks like an [Entity-Attribute-Value table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but if Entity and Attribute are combined into one field, you're kind of stuck.  EAV is already a poor model for querying.  Did they really denormalize it, too?

Comment: @BaconBits It has one more column, but it's all the same value "yes".
It's an ugly source of data.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the SQL side of things it sounds like you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT `option_value` FROM table_name WHERE `option_name` in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4');
```

In PHP it should work out to basically be:

```
<?php
$items = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4');
$itemsStr = implode(',', $users); // returns 'item1','item2','item3','item4'
$sql = "SELECT `option_value` FROM table_name where `option_name` in ({$itemsStr})";
```

This is very rough but hopefully will get you going in the right direction. I'm sure my use of backticks is in the wrong spots

Comment: Yeah this gets a single row, but it's nearly useless unless I can do the same for seconditem and then join the two.

Comment: Try with adding Group by clause for item column

Comment: @JoshiConsultancy The names literally have numbers 1 - 6 at the end so they can't be grouped, because they are all different

Comment: You did not get it. You need to use the column not the value